# What is the easiest way to find where a part of html is defined in the Rails partials and layouts?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, view, reverse

I am working with a fairly large Rails application. I am new to the application and I don't know its structure very well. Sometimes when I browse it I notice something in the views I want to change. I then start to look for the file where a particular region is defined. Sometimes if I want to correct a specific text, I am able to find it quickly by searching for part of it. But sometimes I want to edit a region, which contains very generic words and also generic css classes, like .menu-wrapper, .header-menu etc.. How do you find out quickly in which layout or partial a particular region of a view is defined? The app uses Slim as a templating engine, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [xray-rails](https://github.com/brentd/xray-rails) gem:

In your Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'xray-rails'
end
```

Then:

```
bundle && rm -rf tmp/cache/assets
```

restart your application and it is it. You can now access your layouts/templates/partial data in browser using `ctrl+shift+x` (or `cmd+shift+x` in Mac).